# How to group rows in SQL Server in groups with constrained size without splitting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I think the easiest way to explain this is with an example. All of the below is stored in SQL Server 2012 as table data. Expected amount of data is ~1000-2000 detail rows to process.

I have a set of rows that follows this scheme:

```
Master    Detail    SomeData
Master1   Detail1   <Doesn't matter>
Master1   Detail2   <Doesn't matter>
Master1   Detail3   <Doesn't matter>
Master2   Detail4   <Doesn't matter>
Master2   Detail5   <Doesn't matter>
Master3   Detail6   <Doesn't matter>
Master3   Detail7   <Doesn't matter>
```

I group it into this:

```
Master   DetailCount
Master1   3
Master2   2
Master3   2
```

What I need to do with this is create buckets of masters, where each bucket has at max N details in it. Let's say N is 4 in our case (N will always be bigger than the biggest DetailCount, guaranteed).

This means I want to get this:

N = 4

```
Bucket    Master
1         Master1 <-- can't have more because there is no space 
2         Master2, Master3
```

It doesn't have to be perfect at all. Main requirement is to never split a group (so can't assign Master1 to two buckets). A pseudo-code version that satisfies my needs would be:

```
foreach master, count
  if currentBucketAmount + count > maxBucketAmount
     createNewBucket
     assign master to newBucket
     currentBucket = newBucket
     currentBucketAmount = count
  else
     assign master to currentBucket
     currentBucketAmount += count
```

That's how I would handle it in a C# or Python program but it has to be in SQL. And I don't know enough about SQL.

Should I  just use a cursor for this?

Is there a set-operation that can handle it in a less-procedural way?

Comment: I don't really understand the question but a cursor is definitely not the way to go. I think that what you are trying to do is create a comma separated list of all the details? If that is the case I can toss together a quick example that will show that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, a CSV is not what I need. I need to apply two levels of grouping to the details:

-> Once per master
-> Further into "containers". The amount of containers needed depends on the input.


Requirement is that details from the same "master" can't be split into two containers AND each container must have at most N details in it. The number of details in a container would be the #masters * #details in that master.

Comment: Ahh yes...the age old bin packing problem.

Comment: Seems like a variation on the knapsack problem

Comment: It is similar but I don't care about minimizing the number of buckets. If I need to add some extra buckets (while wasting some space) to avoid splitting details, I am fine with that.

Comment: Can you post a sqlfiddle with some details that we can work with? I assume you must have a bucket size and each of your detail rows has a size? sqlfiddle.com is a great place to post table definitions and such.

Comment: this is much easier if you have a max items per bucket --- is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I will be able to define the max items per bucket.

So I can say "Max amount of items will be 100" for example. It will always be big enough.

Will look into SQLFiddle.com, not familiar with how to setup the example there.

Comment: ok that is to large to do joins, I'll show you how to do it with a recursive CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given @MaxSize

```
WITH MasterCount AS
(
   SELECT Master, Count(Detail) as D_Count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS Ord
   FROM YourTableName
   GROUP BY Master
), MakeBuket AS
(
   SELECT Ord,D_Count AS Total_Count, Master, 1 AS Bucket
   FROM MasterCount
   WHERE Ord = 1
 UNION ALL
   SELECT Next.Ord, 
          CASE WHEN Last.Total_Count+Next.D_Count < @MaxSize 
               THEN Last.Total_Count+Next.D_Count 
               ELSE Next.D_Count END AS Total_Count,
          Master,
          CASE WHEN Last.Total_Count+Next.D_Count < @MaxSize 
               THEN Last.Bucket
               ELSE Last.Bucket+1 END AS Bucket
   FROM MakeBucket Last
   JOIN MasterCount Next ON Last.Ord = Next.Ord - 1
)
SELECT Master, Bucket 
FROM MakeBucket
```

Note, this is just quick code, I did not test this so I might have some syntax issues.

As you can see this is really just a recursive definition of your loop.  There really is no way (I know of) to solve this without a loop.  I'd say if you can it would be better to do this at the client (eg with Linq using Aggregate)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Had to tweak over the OVER clause to have some kind of ordering in the data set, but otherwise it works wonders. I wouldn't know how to express it in SQL so thanks a million!